# How do I only step over editable code in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

When debugging an android application, how do I skip stepping over into library code that belongs to the android framework or a 3rd party?  I don't want to rely on setting breakpoints in my code and using "resume program" because I might skip over the problem.

I want to keep using step over, but only have it go to my project code(code that is editable).  I can add debug step filters but I have to know all the patterns.  I know to exclude android.*. but there are a bunch of 3rd party libraries I don't want to step into either.

Comment: did u get solution of the above problem.